# Pagination not working on the Category Template

Tags: wordpress

I m trying to add the pagination for the category template in my application but when i click on the next option it redirect's me to the page and say no page found. The Same Code i Have written for the blog page too it is working but only in case of categories page it is not working. Can anyone please help me for this

```
<?php
/**
* A Simple Category Template
*/
    get_header();


    $current_page = get_queried_object();
    $category     = $current_page->name;


    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $query = new WP_Query( 
        array(
            'post_type'     => 'post',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'=> 1,
            'category_name' => $category,
            'paged'        => $paged
        )
    );
    ?>
    <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php 
                // Check if there are any posts to display
                if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
                // The Loop
                    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                        $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                        $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, $size)[0];
        ?>
                        <br>
                        <section>
                            <article>
                                <img width="270" height="178" src="<?php echo $image_src; ?>">
                            </article>
                            <nav>
                                <ul>
                                    <?php
                                        foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) ?>
                                            <li> | <?php   echo get_the_date();  ?></li>
                                            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>/">
                                                <?php   the_title();  ?></a></li>
                                            <li>
                                                <img width="40" height="40" src="<?php echo $image_src ?>">
                                            </li>
                                            <li><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </section>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php //echo "<pre>"; ?>
                    <?php //var_dump($query); ?>
                    <?php //echo "</pre>"; ?>

                        <p><?php next_posts_link('Next',$query->max_num_pages); ?></p>
                        <p><?php previous_posts_link('Previous'); ?></p>   
                        <?php  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>   




                <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php 
    get_footer(); 
?>
```

Comment: On the category template are you fetching the child category or post ?

Comment: i m trying to fetch the post of the child category